# Type Initialization Exception c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I looked on another question similar to this but couldn't quite understand what they did to solve the problem.

I am simply passing a value into a public static int:

```
namespace ModNote
{

public partial class homeScreen : Form
{

    public homeScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void gamemodButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundProgram.moduleNumber = 1;
        this.Hide();
        moduleScreen showForm = new moduleScreen();
        showForm.Show();         
    }
```

and this is where this variable is initialized

```
namespace ModNote
{
#region // Setting up Variables
public class backgroundProgram
{
    public static int moduleNumber;     
}
#endregion
```

}

and here a picture of the error: http://puu.sh/opETJ/fb8152d164.png

Thankyou.

edit: initializing the string array causes this error, any problems with this array being initialized? (moduleArray)

```
namespace ModNote
{
#region // Setting up Variables
public class backgroundProgram
{
    public static int moduleNumber;
    public static string[] noteArray;
    public static string[] moduleArray = new string[7] 
    { File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CGP1005M.txt"),
        File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1005M.txt"),
        File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1123M.txt"),
        File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1124M.txt"),
        File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1125M.txt"),
        File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1127M.txt"),
        File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1129M.txt")
    };

}
#endregion
```

}

Comment: That exception usually indicates an exception in a static initializer or constructor.  Since you show neither I assume the actual problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I have just realised it does not work when i initialize my array

Comment: If you can't figure it out you can edit this question and vote to reopen it) or create a new one.

Comment: i have edited the question but do not know how to reopen it as it says i cannot vote on my own post

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is throw here:

```
public static string[] moduleArray = new string[7] 
{ File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CGP1005M.txt"),
    File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1005M.txt"),
    File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1123M.txt"),
    File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1124M.txt"),
    File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1125M.txt"),
    File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1127M.txt"),
    File.ReadAllText(@"ModulesFile\CMP1129M.txt")
};
```

Then one of those lines is throwing an exception.  There are all sorts of reasons for an exception to be thrown when reading from a file - security, not found, in use, etc.

I would suggest moving that logic to the static constructor so you can debug it to find the immediate problem, then add better error handling.

Another option is to *not* read all of that data in the static constructor and instead create an `Initialize` method or something.  Exceptions in static constructors are difficult to handle in general.

Comment: I looked around at using Initialize and dont quite understand it. How would I go about creating a string array, that reads in 7 text files to each location in the array? Ive been stuck on this for an hour now trying to figure it out.

Comment: There's no magical `Initialize` method; I'm just saying create a static method that initializes the data instead of doing it in the constructor.  You'd call that method from your main program on startup. _Syntactically_ there's nothing wrong with what you have, but _something_ is causeing a runtime exception.  You'd need to debug or add error handling to know exactly what the problem is.